# Crash on android 9(presumably on close socket)

Tags: android

I have a couple of crash in google developer console on android 9 devices with backtrace:

```
  #00  pc 0000000000021974  /system/lib64/libc.so (abort+116)
  #01  pc 0000000000456cac  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::Runtime::Abort(char const*)+1064)
  #02  pc 0000000000008cd4  /system/lib64/libbase.so (android::base::LogMessage::~LogMessage()+724)
  #03  pc 00000000002df9bc  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::JavaVMExt::JniAbort(char const*, char const*)+1516)
  #04  pc 0000000000348400  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::JNI::GetIntField(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jfieldID*)+160)
  #05  pc 000000000001e14c  /system/lib64/libopenjdk.so (FileDispatcherImpl_preClose0+24)
  #06  pc 000000000011562c  /system/framework/arm64/boot.oat (java.lang.System.setErr0 [DEDUPED]+172)
  #07  pc 00000000002ea4d4  /system/framework/arm64/boot.oat (sun.nio.ch.DatagramDispatcher.preClose [DEDUPED]+52)
  #08  pc 0000000000448714  /system/framework/arm64/boot.oat (sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.implCloseSelectableChannel+180)
  #09  pc 000000000043dd44  /system/framework/arm64/boot.oat (java.nio.channels.spi.AbstractSelectableChannel.implCloseChannel+52)
  #10  pc 00000000003fde60  /system/framework/arm64/boot.oat (java.nio.channels.spi.AbstractInterruptibleChannel.close+128)
  #11  pc 0000000000447d1c  /system/framework/arm64/boot.oat (sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finalize+92)
  #12  pc 0000000000182654  /system/framework/arm64/boot-core-libart.oat (java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize+100)
  #13  pc 00000000001828dc  /system/framework/arm64/boot-core-libart.oat (java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.runInternal+492)
  #14  pc 000000000011084c  /system/framework/arm64/boot-core-libart.oat (java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run+76)
  #15  pc 000000000025cfc8  /system/framework/arm64/boot.oat (java.lang.Thread.run+72)
  #16  pc 0000000000545b88  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+584)
  #17  pc 00000000000cf698  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+200)
  #18  pc 000000000044f524  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::InvokeWithArgArray(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, art::ArtMethod*, art::(anonymous namespace)::ArgArray*, art::JValue*, char const*)+104)
  #19  pc 00000000004505f0  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::InvokeVirtualOrInterfaceWithJValues(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, jvalue*)+424)
  #20  pc 000000000047ae10  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::Thread::CreateCallback(void*)+1260)
  #21  pc 0000000000082264  /system/lib64/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+36)
  #22  pc 0000000000023178  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+68)
```

I can't reproduce this on my own environments. 
Application specific: it works with an external device. After connecting to wifi network app tries to connect to device via raw socket(via Apache MINA). 
Do you have any idea about reasons(steps to reproduce) of that crash?